Laravel - SQLSTATE[42000]:Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'end_date'
In my Laravel version 10 application, I have created users table using migration. How I want to add new columns. I have this:
public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('student_id')->constrained('students')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('course_id')->constrained('courses')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->enum('type', ['monthly', 'annual']); // Type d'abonnement
            $table->timestamp('start_date');
            $table->timestamp('end_date');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('subscriptions');
    }
};

When I did:
php artisan migrate

I got this error:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1067 Invalid default value for 'end_date' 
(Connection: mysql, SQL: create table `subscriptions` 
(`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `student_id` bigint unsigned not null, `course_id` bigint unsigned not null, 
`type` enum('monthly', 'annual') 
not null, `start_date` timestamp not null, `end_date` timestamp not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) 
default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

How do I get it resolved?
Thanks

I guess you should configure your end_date field to be nullable, since you already have data


This error is comming  because  MySQL timestamp columns require a
valid default value

public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('student_id')->constrained('students')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('course_id')->constrained('courses')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->enum('type', ['monthly', 'annual']); 
        $table->timestamp('start_date')->useCurrent();
        $table->timestamp('end_date')->nullable(); // Make end_date nullable
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

